# Powershell strings are not concatenating properly

Tags: string, powershell, filepath, illegal-characters

So I have

```
$Logfilename = "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo"
Write-Host $Logfilename
E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo


$Newname = $Logfilename + ".log"
Write-Host $Newname
.logeployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo


Get-Content -Path "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo.log"
#returns file normally
```

However, when I try to run the Get-Content from a variable name, I get this error. It's also odd because the error message shows one string, but the Write-Host above, `.logeployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo`,  shows a different one.

```
Get-Content -Path $Newname
Get-Content : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content -Path $Newname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (E:\Deployment L...roductInfo.log:String) [Get-Content], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo.log' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content -Path $Newname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:\Deployment L...roductInfo.log:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I am completely lost as to what is happening here. The file definitely exists at the given path. I have tried adding a `.replace` for hidden \r and \n characters to no avail. I have tried writing the variable contents via `Out-String` and adding the `.log` then and the same thing happens. Is there any explanation or fix to this?

Comment: Your code looks strange ... There are missing quotes in your first line, I suppose that's a copy-paste error? Please share your actual script and the error messages separately. You might have extra spaces in your path, or mabe the "-" is actually a long dash, etc. What output do you get when you run "dir 'E:\Deployment Logs'"?

Comment: running dir E:\Deployment Logs lists all the files in that folder. I have added the quotes to the first line and confirmed it was a copy-paste error.

Comment: What I meant: include the output *in your question*

Comment: If you try to concatenate paths use `Join-Path`.

Comment: How can your code be `$Newname = $Logfilename + ".log"` if the output of the next line, `Write-Host $Newname`, is `.logeployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo`? Because your error is due to the fact that `.logeployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo` isn't a valid file name.

Comment: @BaconBits thats exactly what i was thinking. It's weird because thats the output of the variable when i write to host, but then in the error message you see what it *should* be. So im unsure why it's printing weird.

Comment: @Alex_P this is trying to simply add a ".log" to the string variable so I can use the path elsewhere. the rest of the path is fine.

Comment: I'm speculating, but it's possible you *might* have a special character in one of your strings that's causing the cursor to move back to the start of the console line with ```write-host``` after it's written the ```$Logfilename``` part of ```$NewLine```. If you imagine it writes ```E:\Deployment Logs\20201026``` and then goes back to the start of the line and writes ```.log``` it would appear like you've shown it by overwriting ```E:\D``` with ```.log```. Can you try ```Write-Host $Logfilename.Length``` and ```Write-Host $Newname.Length```.

Comment: @marsze running `dir 'E:\Deployment Logs` returns 200+ log files that are all stored in that same folder.

Comment: @mclayton
```PS E:\Deployment Plans> $Logfilename.length
44
PS E:\Deployment Plans> $Newname.length
48
```

Comment: Hmmm - I get ```PS C:\Windows\System32> "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo".Length -> 43```. I think you've got a non-printing character hiding at the end of ```$Logfilename```. Can you try this: ```[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Logfilename)``` and just paste the last few lines of the output? Mine ends ```73 110 102 111``` for reference.

Comment: the last 5 lines go ```73
110
102
111
13```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the conversation in comments, your script file has a hidden [Carriage Return](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm) character at the end of the string in the line `$Logfilename = "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo"` (which hasn't been replicated into the script in your question).

When you output the string using `write-host` the Carriage Return moves the cursor back to the start of the console line and then carries on writing the rest of the string.

A simple repro is:

```bsh
PS> "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo$([char]0x000D).log"
.logeployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo
```

Carriage Return is not a valid character in filenames, which is why you're also seeing the error. It also looks like it's being stripped out of the error message so it's just showing the "expected" value of the two strings concatenated:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo.log' because it does not exist.
```

This probably happened because you cut & pasted the original value from some other system and you picked up the hidden character without knowing it.

To fix it, just delete the last few characters in the line `$Logfilename = "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo"` and then re-type them manually. You'll probably notice as you delete characters that one of the times you press <kbd>del</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> nothing will seem to happen - that's when you're deleting the non-printing character.

**Update**

In case the comments get deleted, we solved the issue with the following tests:

```bsh
PS E:\Deployment Plans> $Logfilename.length
44

PS E:\Deployment Plans> $Newname.length
48
```

whereas

```
PS> "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo".Length
43

PS> "E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo.log".Length
47
```

which told us there was probably an extra non-printing character at the end of `$Logfilename`.

Next:

```
PS> [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("E:\Deployment Logs\20201026 - 1_ProductInfo.log".)
.
.
73
110
102
111
```

but

```
PS> [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Logfilename)
.
.
73
110
102
111
13
```

So the extra character was UTF character 13 (decimal), which is U+000D, i.e. Carriage Return - see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm

Comment: Thank you! This was actually not copy pasted but was within my script. I removed the extra character using ```$Logfilename.Substring(0,$LogfileName.Length-1)```